# Setting up a cron job in Windows

Tags: windows, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have to download a file from an SFTP server everyday. I have the program which retrieves the file from the server but I was thinking of setting up a cron job (or anything similar) to automate that. We are a Windows shop and need to set up the cron job in Windows.

Answer (score 112):

The windows equivalent to a cron job is a scheduled task.

A scheduled task can be created as described by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7195524/2675672) and [Rudu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7195531/2675672), but it can also be done command line with `schtasks` (if you for instance need to script it or add it to version control).

An example:

```
schtasks /create /tn calculate /tr calc /sc weekly /d MON /st 06:05 /ru "System"
```

Creates the task calculate, which starts the calculator(calc) every monday at 6:05 (should you ever need that.)

All available commands can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28WS.10%29.aspx

It works on windows server 2008 as well as windows server 2003.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Any way to see the currently active tasks on the terminal?

Comment: I love this! Thanks for putting it up here. @gberth schtasks /query shows all of them. The documentation shows many more options.

Answer (score 84):

1. Make sure you logged on as an **administrator** or you have the same access as an administrator.
2. **Start**->**Control Panel**->**System and Security**->**Administrative Tools**->**Task Scheduler**
3. **Action**->**Create Basic Task**->Type a name and Click Next
4. Follow through the wizard.

Comment: or just run `Win+R` then execute `taskschd.msc`

Comment: Is there a way to import/export windows scheduled tasks?

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Yes. Action menu -> Import/Export in Task Scheduler. It'll be a xml file.

Answer (score 13):

There's [pycron](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pycron/) which I really as a Cron implementation for windows, but there's also the built in scheduler which should work just fine for what you need (Control Panel -> Scheduled Tasks -> Add Scheduled Task).

Comment: The link seems working, it takes to the download page.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/ seems like a maintained solution.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to use [Scheduled Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks) you can use the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) which will allow you to use cron jobs like on Linux.

To make sure cron is actually running you can type `service cron status` from within the Linux terminal. If it isn't currently running then type `service cron start` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to thank @Vincent Stevenson, @s-hunter

Go to `Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Task Scheduler--> Create Task`

1. Task Scheduler, Create Task
2. Give the Task a title
3. Go to Actions
4. Go to CMD to find the path,

   Python, import sys, sys.executable

   (this tells you what the **Program/script field** should be populated with: "some path
   with Appdata mostly")

   like:C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
5. **Arguments**: name of the python script (like run.py)
6. **Start in**: dir location of python script (like:C:\Users\admin\Documents\my_python_project)
7. Go to Triggers, schedule as you like
8. Test the script by running it

Answer (score 3):

**For those wanting to use cron in Windows 10/11 with WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)**

Here are the steps needed:

1. Install a linux distribution
2. Setup crontab
3. Create Windows scheduled task so WSL gets run on startup

**1. Install a linux distribution**

Open a powershell (admin) terminal. Run

```
wsl --list --online
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/AFnHOO9.png]

Choose one the distros available and install one by running

```
wsl --install -d <Distro>
```

**2. Setup crontab**

Open a powershell (admin) terminal. Run

```
wsl
```

You should be in the bash linux distro command line now (first time you might be prompted to create a user/pass. Do so). Run

```
sudo service cron status
```

To see if cron is running. If it isn't, run

```
sudo service cron start
```

Check again the status, it should be running now.

To edit the cron job, run

```
crontab -e
```

For example (backup the pic directory at 20:58 everyday):

```
58 20 * * * rsync -av /mnt/c/Users/jlo/Pictures/ /mnt/c/Users/jlo/PicBackup/$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S)/
```

Save and exit

**3. Create a Windows scheduled task so WSL gets run on startup**

*a) In order for the Windows scheduled task to run WSL on startup without requiring to enter a password every time it runs the 'service start cron' command, you need to edit visudo by running:*

```
sudo visudo
```

And adding at the bottom of the file the following:

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service cron start
```

Save and exit.

*b) Create a scheduled task*

Open Start > Type 'Task scheduler' > Create basic task > Trigger: 'when the computer starts' > Action 'Start a program' > C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe > In the 'Add arguments' field, add

```
sudo /usr/sbin/service cron start
```

[image: Task scheduler config]

Save the task. It should now be listed among the other tasks in the Task scheduler.

And you're good to go. I suggest restarting the machine and checking if cron is running (PS admin terminal > wsl > sudo service cron status) and if it's running, configure and test your first cron job. Enjoy!

Some sources I used to figure this out:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands
- https://www.howtogeek.com/746532/how-to-launch-cron-automatically-in-wsl-on-windows-10-and-11/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20180217043628/http://webgnuru.com/linux/rsync_incremental.php

Answer (score 1):

There are also cmdlets in powershell for this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-2-define-a-scheduled-task-with-multiple-actions

The linked example:

```
PS C:\> $actions = (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'foo.ps1'), (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'bar.ps1')
PS C:\> $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At '9:15 AM'
PS C:\> $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId 'DOMAIN\user' -RunLevel Highest
PS C:\> $settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable -WakeToRun
PS C:\> $task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $actions -Principal $principal -Trigger $trigger -Settings $settings

PS C:\> Register-ScheduledTask 'baz' -InputObject $task
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to create a scheduled task.

```
iwr https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jqknono/389a4e2784f838bc8b095878deba0704/raw/abe508119fcf3091ff1ce901063c2e1404f62639/Schedule-Task.ps1 | iex ; Add-CommandScheduledTask
```

Check the script on https://gist.github.com/jqknono/389a4e2784f838bc8b095878deba0704

Three commands offered:

- Add-SimpleScheduledTask
- Add-ScriptScheduledTask
- Add-CommandScheduledTask

`Add-CommandScheduledTask` is the easiest way to run a program intervally.

Task added in the Task Scheduler.

[image]