# Where to place cron job code in my core php project?

Tags: codeigniter, operating-system

I have the code for cron job but i don't know where place this code in my project folder.

The code is:

```
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/cnl/myscript.php
```

Comment: I think that's something you'd generally do in the OS and not in PHP ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: Which operating system you used?

Comment: I have used Windows 7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows

Comment: But i want to use cron job for live site in php

Comment: You don't need to put your cron php code in your project folder. There is no rule.  Place it in any suitable directory and give the path to your crontab.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't. You can't place OS(crontab) configuration code to PHP code and expect that it will manage your OS. But You can:

1) Create method at CodeIgniter's controller (for example at `application/controllers/welcome.php` create

```
function hello(){
   echo "I'm a function!";
}
```

and then call it from command line as

```
cd /your/path/to/codeigniter/ && php5 index.php welcome hello
```

If it works correctly, add this task to You crontab via command line or some GUI (cPanel/ISPManager/VestaCP/etc)

2) If You need to add Your line to cron and in fact Your question is not connected to CodeIgniter, I advice You to search "how to add cron job?", You'll find many results