# How to schedule a Hibernate program once in a day

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring REST with Hibernate and I have developed a program in which data is coming from database calculate and it is updated into another table in database. But I want to run this program once in a day at a given time because I want to calculate result only one time in a day. How can I do this?

Here is my **DAO** class

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
  public List<Result> getPostList() throws Exception {
      session = sessionFactory.openSession();
      tx = session.beginTransaction();

      Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Post.class);
      ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
      projList.add(Projections.sum("val"), "topValue");
      projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("userId"), "uid");
      cr.addOrder(Order.desc("topValue"));
      cr.setProjection(projList);
      cr.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Result.class));
      List<Result> postList = cr.list();
      // please make sure that you are using the class field name rather than database field name in below query.
      String updateHql = "update Result set topValue = :topValue where id = :uid";
      Query query = null;
      int count = 1;
      for(Result result : postList){
        query=session.createQuery(updateHql);
       // query.setLong("topValue", result.getTopValue());
        query.setLong("topValue", count);
        query.setLong("uid", result.getUid());
        count++;
        query.executeUpdate();
        session.flush();
      }

      session.flush();
      tx.commit();
      return postList;
  }
```

Here is my **Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/posts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Result> getEmployee() {

    List<Result> postList = null;
    try {
        postList = profileService.getPostList();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return postList;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://quartz-scheduler.org/
  You need a scheduler for it. You can configure a method to be scheduled everyday as explained below in spring:

1) In spring config:

```
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10" />
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10" />

<task:annotation-driven scheduler="scheduler" executor="executor" />
```

2) Enable annotation:

```
<context:component-scan annotation-config="true" base-package="" />
```

3) Annotate the method with @Scheduled annotation which you want to be scheduled

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 12 * * ?")
public void scheduledTask(){
}
```

Above cron expression will schedule the method at 12pm (noon) every day.
Link for some generic cron expressions: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Comment: Yes i am using spring .Where will i use @Scheduled(cron="0 0 12 * * ?") ? In my controller or DAO class.

Comment: Edited my post. You need to create a Main class, load the spring config file in it. Create a method anywhere where you dao object is injected. create a method, annotate it with @Scheduled and make a call to your Dao method.

Comment: i have created a method in my controller. i want to ask if this method will come in my void main() method. Please chk my controller

Comment: If you leave the application running in server. Then no need of main() method. Your spring config need to be loaded that's it. Just put the @Scheduled on it. Use this annotation @Scheduled(fixedDelay =30000) for quick debugging. Will fire that method after every 30 seconds.

Comment: i created main() method now how to load spring config into it?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {

  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("your-spring-config.xml");

 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84538/discussion-between-nadeem-ahmed-and-amit-bhati).

Comment: Please check my main() method.....    @Scheduled(fixedDelay =30000)
 public static void main(String[] args){
   new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml"); 
   ProfileDataService profileService = null;
   try {
   profileService.getPostList();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: getPostList() is in my DAO class.

Comment: No create a method in your dao class or any other bean...then create a method, say, public void scheduleTask(){}..Call profileService.getPostList(); in it.

Comment: But how can i set it for specific time.. like 12:00 am at night

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using

- Cron job which runs on your server and hits the page updating database. You can schedule tasks on the server. Which will be always depended on the machine.
- You may consider [spring schedulers.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) In this case you will be adding the scheduler part to your application. This will of-course be machine independent. If I was the one to choose, I would be preferring spring scheduler.

Relevant links :
[Setting up a cron job in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do some readings about [Spring Task Execution and Scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html). It's very well documented.
Basically:

1. Implement Runnable interface in your task (be sure your code is thread safe!)
2. Obtain `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` bean
3. Schedule your task following like:

   scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("* 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));