# Update database by script or session?

Tags: php, bash, shell, nette

I have function in php, where I update a database. I have url something like http://localhost/products/feed/update

How can I update database every 15 minutes? It is better script or session or how to do this?

Comment: Cronjob, simple and easy.

Comment: I am windows user, so i can´t.

Comment: Regular windows (as in 7/8/10)? or Windows Server?

Comment: Windows 7, i will update on 10, but next month...

Comment: There's task scheduler then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows

Comment: thx, do you know code, for curl on my in bat file?

Comment: Nope, and not going to provide it either, otherwise you wouldn't learn anything :)

Comment: thx for hel, but how cen i get request in batch script. start http://localhost/product/feed/update open url in web browser, but i need only do request on this url...any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The best is a cron (or a scheduled task on windows).

The good question is also: do you really NEED the database to be updated every 15 minutes?

Can't you just check the last update timestamp upon request, and update it once for every 15 minutes that passed? That's often the simplest solution.

Comment: I dont know how to chcek it... start session? or what can start my php function in some time some timechec ajax function?(i know how to do it only on page load and function like this....)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to be PHP script?

You could have stored procedure run by event every 15 mins.

For example in MySQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html