# Change the value after expiration date PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm beginner in PHP MySQL,  I have system that after you register/add the customer information it will change the status after 30 days.

**Scenario** 
In my add customer page, I have forms like Date Start, Date Expiration and Status.

*Date Start* - automatically set the date today 
*Expiration* - Automatically set the Date Start + 30 days 
*Expiration2* - Automatically set the Expiration date + 90 days 
*Status* - Status of the customer (if newly registered the status value will be **`FRESH`** if after **30days** the status will change to **`INACTIVE`** if after **90days** it will change to **`DORMANT`**.

This my code for **`dateStart`** and **`dateExpired`** , **`dateExpired2`** but I don't know how to code the **`status`** process.

```
$dateStart= Date('Y-m-d');
$dateExpired = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateStart. ' + 30 days'));
$dateExpired2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateExpired2. ' + 90days'));

echo '<input type="text" name= "dateStart" value="'. $dateStart.'"/>';
echo '<input type="text" name= "dateExpired" value="'. $dateExpired .'"/>';
```

Comment: you can set a cron every night which checks the date difference. If difference is 30days, change the status.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Sorry I'm beginner, don't know how to do it.

Comment: the how depends on your machine. [windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows) and [linux](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run a script like this at a scheduled interval, it can automatically update your user's status':

```
$dateStart= date('Y-m-d');
$dateExpired = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateStart. ' + 30 days'));
$dateExpired2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateStart. ' + 90days'));

$status = "FRESH";

if(strtotime($dateStart)<strtotime('-30 days')){
   $status = "INACTIVE";
}

if(strtotime($dateStart)<strtotime('-90 days')){
   $status = "DORMANT";
}

//Run sql update query to set status
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) for sql update query

Comment: Thanks but how do I know if the Dormant and Inactive condition is working ?

Comment: Change $dateStart to a date like '2015-04-01' and echo $status

Answer (score 3):

Trigger a cron job.

- You should write code in a .php file, to do what you require(change status if date has exceeded 30 days or 90 days)
- You should make sure that, you file doesn't have any session related to it.

I have added following images , refer them

[image]

I have added a cron which runs once in a day. and in your server, it looks like this.

[image]

Comment: You should write code as suggested by @tkav and set a cron for that page which runs automatically every night at 12 am.

Comment: Where can I find this CRON?

Comment: It also have in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: No... cron is only on cpanel,

Comment: Any other possible answer? @Tkav has a good answer but I don't know how to try if **`DORMANT`**  and **`INACTIVE`**. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92339/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-edmhar).