# How to log scrapy spiders running from script

Tags: python, exception, logging, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi all i have multiple spider running from the script. Script will schedule daily once.

1. I want to log the infos, errors separately. log filename must be a **spider_infolog_[date]** and **spider_errlog_[date]**
   i am trying following code,

spider __init__  file

```
from twisted.python import log
import logging
LOG_FILE = 'logs/spider.log'
ERR_FILE = 'logs/spider_error.log'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filemode='w+', filename=LOG_FILE)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR, filemode='w+', filename=ERR_FILE)
observer = log.PythonLoggingObserver()
observer.start()
```

within spider:

```
import logging
.
.
.
logging.error(message)
```

2. if any exception happens in spider code [like i am fetching start urls from the MysqlDB, if the connection fails i need to close the specific spider not other spiders because i am running all spiders from the script]

   raise CloseSpider(message)

is above code sufficent to close the particular spider ?

### EDIT @eLRuLL

```
import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
LOG_FILE = 'logs/spider.log'
ERR_FILE = 'logs/spider_error.log'
configure_logging()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filemode='w+', filename=LOG_FILE)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR, filemode='w+', filename=ERR_FILE)
```

i have put the above code in a script that schedules spiders. not working file not created but in console i got log messages.

### EDIT 2

i have added install_root_handler=False in configure_logging() it gives all the console output in spider.log file error is not differenciated.

```
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
```

Comment: `CloseSpider` (calling it from within the spider) should be sufficient for closing a spider.

Comment: thank you @eLRuLL. can you look into my first query?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but maybe you can use `configure_logging`, check this documentation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script Maybe later you can postprocess the script to separate logging levels.

Comment: edited the post please check @eLRuLL

Comment: yeah, like I told you I haven't tried it yet, what about passing `Settings`? you could specify logging details there and then pass it to the script, check here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#logging-configuration, specifically `LOG_FILE`

Comment: here you can check how to pass settings to the script: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script

Comment: yupe @eLRuLL i have seen that. but in my case i have two files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95718/discussion-between-sabeena-and-elrull).

Comment: can anyone reply to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
from scrapy import cmdline

cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl myspider --logfile mylog.log".split())
```

Put that script in the path where you put `scrapy.cfg`