# How can I run a PHP Script automatically Daily in WAMP / Windows Environment?

Tags: php, cron, wamp, scheduled-tasks

I need to run a PHP script at the scheduled time daily to update some fields in database. How I can do this?

I tried with windows scheduler and it not running the script I cant figure our the error.

Is there any tutorial or steps which helps to understand the working, so as to configure.

My Bat File:

> H:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe H:\wamp\www\file\file.php

Test PHP Script:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: Use cron job. [cron job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows)

Comment: please check the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with windows scheduler with command `php full\link\to\php\file.php`, if this not working probably link to `php.exe` file is not properly linked in systems `PATH` variable. So you can try then something like this `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe C:\wamp\www\test.php`.

Also you can use `at` cmd command to set up schedule task, you can read more about it [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx)

**Solution:**

PHP File:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("H:\\wamp\\www\\file\\newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

BAT File:

> H:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe H:\wamp\www\file\file.php

Double Click BAT File will Create a newfile.txt.

Comment: kindly check my update in the question i have mentioned my BAT content.

Comment: I don't understand, it works perfectly on my machine. Maybe there's error in your php script?

Comment: I have included the test PHP script which I am running. Can you tell me about your Environment Set up.?

Comment: CAn you past you BAT file content.?

Comment: The problem is your fopen(), because it creates newfile.txt somewhere where task scheduler starts, try to use full path `$myfile = fopen("H:\\wamp\\www\\file\\newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");` this should work

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.bat` file with following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
path\to\php.exe -f "path\to\your_file.php"
```

Now schedule the task in `Task Scheduler` using the created `.bat` file.

Answer (score 0):

You, also, may have to look at one of the following applications:

1. http://cronw.sourceforge.net/    (*free*)
2. http://www.z-cron.com/
3. http://www.visualcron.com/

Or use [**this Google search**](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=windows+cron&oq=windows+cron&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4737j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) (Windows cron)