# how to autorun php file per day

Tags: php

The website is written in .php with the connection of MySQL
I had a file that's named `PMautoemail.php` It can be run successfully but I only want it to run once a day. Cronjob couldn't be set up as I am running in a windows server and this website will be run by other people too. What should I do?

Comment: [Setting Up A Cronjob In Windows Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442040/setting-up-a-cronjob-in-windows-xampp)

Comment: @Lim, Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932617/how-can-i-run-a-php-script-automatically-daily-in-wamp-windows-environment

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows Task Scheduler to run the file daily. Think of it as cronjob for Windows.

**EDIT:**

Another option: Windows Sub-system for Linux. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: Other than Windows Task Scheduler? Is there any other way than that, because it's not what I wanted.

Comment: There is one other option:Windows Subsystem for Linux. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10. Using it you can run cronjobs like linux.

Comment: I just found out that I will be using iPage to display the website, will the webside auto run the file in the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can't use CronJob, you can always start file in background and set some sleep. It's not proper solution, but sometimes be only option in some cases:

```
// init_linux.php
exec('php my_cron.php &'); 

// init_win.php
pclose(popen("start /B php my_cron.php", "r"));

// my_cron.php

// [... do some stuff ...];
sleep(60 * 60 * 24); // sleep for 1 day
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the date and time of the script execution in the database. Then at the beginning of your code, check if the script has been run today. Stop the script if it is running today