# How to change a field value only once after a period of time using php-mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, time, cron, auto-update

I have a table with some fields.`status` and `starting_timestamps` are two of them.
the default value of `status` is **T**. I want to change this to **F** after the 10 days.
`starting_timestamps` stores the time of starting.How can i do this? Iam in php-mysql platform

Comment: how do you want to do this by php or from mysql.

Comment: Numerous options - run a cron, remove the status column and just calculate it in queries, update on select

Comment: @jewelhuq .i want auto updation of the table.whats the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a php file e.g. cron.php with the following code.

   In the following code, variables $host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $db, $table are to be replaced with actual database related values.

   ```
   <?php
   $host = 'localhost';
   $mysql_user = 'root';
   $mysql_password = 'your password';
   $db = 'databaename';
   $table='actual table name';

   $link = mysql_connect($host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
   if (!$link) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   // make foo the current db
   $db_selected = mysql_select_db($db, $link);
   if (!$db_selected) {
       die ('Can\'t use '.$db.': ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $result = mysql_query('UPDATE `'.$table.'`
       SET status=\'F\' 
       WHERE
       (UNIX_TIMESTAMP( now( ) ) - `starting_timestamps`) /86400 = 10');


   if (!$result) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   //close connection
   mysql_close($link);
   ?>
   ```

Now using your hosting cpanel, go to `cronjobs` settings.

Here `create a new cronjob which should run everyday`. For cron job, enter following command.

```
/usr/bin/php -f 'path_to_php_script.php'
```

You can check attached image for how to create cron job.

Here make sure that 'path_to_php_script.php' is real physical path to cron.php file on hosting server.

[image]

Comment: i want auto update after 10 days.how can i do that by this query?

Comment: You can write above query into php script and set that script into cronjob to run every day.

e.g. /usr/bin/php -f path_to_php_script

Comment: @AlpeshPanchal You should include this information in your "Answer", otherwise it will be removed as not answering the question. The 10 days is mentioned in the original question.

Comment: I added detailed instructions in the above Answer for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Well Simple.

Create a php file and then from php file run the above query and start a cron job that will run this file everyday at certain time automatically and thus you will get your desire result.

Comment: If you are in windows but do not know how to setup cron job follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows