# How to run task scheduler in windows 10 with Laravel

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I just want to ask how to use it's task scheduling feature on windows machine (my local machine).

I've read it's documentation and I've notice that it's using a Cron.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: may be it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows

Comment: after too much research I found proper solution for windows server, see here I shared full details about how to use Laravel scheduler in windows server. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69954322/14344959

Answer (score 43):

To run Laravel Scheduler in Windows 10 you need:

1. Create batch file, like this one and save it:

`cd c:\laravel-project\`

`c:\php5\php.exe artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1`

2. Go to Windows 10 Task Scheduler (fast way is press `Win+R` and enter `taskschd.msc`).
3. Click `Create basic task`, choose `When I logon` trigger and then choose `Start a program` -> your `.bat` file.
4. Check `Open properties dialog` option and click `Finish`.
5. In task properties click `Triggers`, then click `New` and add new trigger `Repeat task every - 1 minute`.

Now this task will run Laravel scheduler every one minute.

Comment: Do I need to put the path of my php.exe or the path of my project?

Comment: If you're askig about step 1, then answer will be - both. Please look at step 1: `cd` command will change current directory to your project's directory. Then you need to use path to your `php.exe` file.

Comment: what will be the content of my .bat file? I'm still confuse of the two paths.

Comment: I think step 1 is very clear. I will give you another example though, maybe it will be helpful for you: first line of `.bat` file: `cd c:\myprojects\mylaravelproject\` and second line `c:\php5\php.exe artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1`

Comment: Hi guys, I configure all like in the answer above. 
If I run my task In the Schedule panel It runs vey well, but doesnt run in the time I specify, can u help me ? I dont know why. 
Thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, I had to tackle this today also.  I used Alexey's solution with one small change.  I am running XAMPP on a Win 10 machine, Laravel  5.3.  I created the batch file and task as he outlined but changed the second line of .bat to 'php artisan schedule:run'.   Worked like a charm.  Also, I placed my .bat in my project root just to keep everything in one spot.  Hope this helps anyone else trying to do same.

Comment: Thanks. That really helped.

Comment: create file .bat (example: c:/command.bat)
Write in file .bat -> C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\'NameProject'\artisan schedule:run Go Step 2

Comment: Can you explain this command `c:\php5\php.exe artisan schedule:run 1>> NUL 2>&1` ?. Especially this parameters `1>> NUL 2>&1`

Answer (score -1):

I still did not run the schedule, the solution was just to add / d to the path in

```
cd c:\laravel-project\
```

in

```
cd /d c:\laravel-project\
```