# Command schedule in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to a execute scheduled command every five minutes in background. I use this code

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

        $schedule->command('read:mail')->cron('*/1 * * * * *')->sendOutputTo(storage_path().'/logs/output.txt')->withoutOverlapping();

    }
```

I suppose that this code is fine, when i use `php artisan scheduler:run`  command works, but doesn't work every five minutes in background. ¿Any idea?

Comment: Full Laravel version?

Comment: Laravel v.5.0. Commands like everyFiveMinutes() doesn´t work.

Comment: Did you add `* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` in your Cron entries?

Comment: No idea what are you saying... can you explain better?

Comment: `*/1` is the same a `*`. You probably want `*/5`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the scheduler you need to add a Cron entry in your server, this line will call the Laravel scheduler every minute and do the tasks.

There is the line you need to add to your Crontab:

`* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

In case you are using **Ubuntu** to edit your crontab you can run `crontab -e` and add the line on the bottom.

You can read more on the official docs about [Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction).

If you are using **Windows** you can follow [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305146/how-to-run-task-scheduler-in-windows-10-with-laravel-5-1) to add a task to the Windows task scheduler.

Comment: crontab -e in the apache server (or whatever) or in the project?

Comment: I suppose if it´s Windows i need to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305146/how-to-run-task-scheduler-in-windows-10-with-laravel

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre sorry, I tought you where using Ubuntu, yes, for Windows you can follow that guide.