# How to correctly execute a cron job?

Tags: php, laravel, console

I'm trying to run a cron job in my laravel project. I run the following command

```
* * * * * cd c:/PaginasWeb/intranet php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

and I miss the error

> The system can not find the path specified

But that's the route where my project is located, It's the first time I try to do a cron job, and I do not know if I'm doing wrong. The command is executed from c: /

Comment: What operating system are you running on?

Comment: How exactly are you running this? Because that looks very like a Windows path, and Windows doesn't have a crontab in the same way that Linux does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run task scheduler in windows 10 with Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305146/how-to-run-task-scheduler-in-windows-10-with-laravel-5-1)

Comment: I'm in windows server 2012 R2

Comment: You'd need a `&&` between the path and `php`

Comment: @aynber now it appears "*" is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or batch file executable.

Comment: How are you attempting this? Windows doesn't use the same type of cron that linux uses, so this string won't work for you. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows and https://moreabout.tech/creating-cron-jobs-in-windows-8-and-server-2012-or-any-version-of-windows/