# Why it cant loop the function every 5 minutes? (cronjob, task scheduling laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, scheduling

I'm trying to set up a scheduling task that can run every five minutes, but it only works 1 time, after the first five minutes, the other five minutes dont do the function correctly.

//depresiasicounter.php

```
protected $signature = 'updates:depresiasicounter';

public function handle()
{
    $aktivatb = Aktivatb::where('id','1')->first();
        $aktivatb->nilai= $aktivatb->nilai-$aktivatb->depresiasi;
        $aktivatb->total_depresiasi = $aktivatb->total_depresiasi+$aktivatb->depresiasi;
    $aktivatb->save();
}
```

//kernel.php

```
protected $commands = [
        Commands\DepresiasiCounter::class,
    ];


protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->commands('updates:depresiasicounter')->everyFiveMinutes();
}
```

I expect it can be work until the value of $aktivatb->nilai to 0, but it only works 1 time

Comment: use `$schedule->command(` without `s` and try again?

Comment: i tried but it still works for 1 time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup cron so it could run the php artisan schedule:run command every minute, so you need to add the following Cron entry to your server.

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. Then, Laravel evaluates your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

When using the scheduler, you only need to add the following Cron entry to your server.

Comment: Can i run cron in localhost? i tried to use
php artisan schedule:run
but it still dont works

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: im using windows10 pro

Comment: Yes, you can but first You have to set CRON for Laravel on your local system

Answer (score 1):

A Scheduled task is basically the system is running a command

```
php /project-path/artisan schedule:run
```

every given amount of time.

In **Linux** environment, people use cron to handle this by creating a crontab

```
* * * * * php /project-path/artisan schedule:run
```

Those asterisk signs in front of the command indicates the interval of the 
command.

In **Windows** environment, you can refer to the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305146/how-to-run-task-scheduler-in-windows-10-with-laravel-5-1).

Or you can setup a virtual machine and run the cron job inside the machine.