# How to replicate a cron job in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, cron-task

I'm familiar with Task Scheduler but I'm struggling to convert a Unix cron task.

I'm using an open source kanban board call [kanboard](https://kanboard.net/documentation/cronjob).

For analytics it requires a task to be run each day. These are the instructions from the developer....

**Configuration on Unix and Linux platforms**

There are multiple ways to define a cronjob on Unix/Linux operating systems, this example is for Ubuntu 14.04. The procedure is similar to other systems.

Edit the crontab of your web server user:

```
sudo crontab -u www-data -e
```

Example to execute the daily cronjob at 8am:

```
0 8 * * * cd /path/to/kanboard && ./kanboard cronjob >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Note: the cronjob process must have write access to the database in case you are using Sqlite. Usually, running the cronjob under the web server user is enough.

Unfortunately there are no equivalent instructions for Windows based systems.

**Is there any software that runs on windows that will just take unix commands and schedule a task or any other way of doing the same in Windows?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows

Comment: What about http://www.visualcron.com/  http://www.z-cron.com/ or http://cronw.sourceforge.net/