# Crawl website every x minutes/seconds using scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I'm crawling a blog using Scrapy using the command "scrapy crawl posts".
I need to check for new posts every 5 minutes.
How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using UNIX or are you on windows?

Comment: @kiran.koduru windows :)

Comment: @user6712306 this not code sharing site plz put your try code after you need help then ask freely

Comment: Hook up to a Cron job for more info : http://newcoder.io/scrape/part-5/

Comment: Can you tell us about the version of Windows you are using?

Comment: @kiran.koduru 8.1

Comment: You can check the link in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/crontab` file to include this line. It will setup your script to run every 5 minutes.

```
*/5 *   * * *   unix-username   cd /your/path/to/scrapy-project/;scrapy crawl posts
```

For windows you can take a look at the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows)