# whenever gem error No such file or directory - crontab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I dont know what problem is this.
[this my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY3bE.png)

This is console output.

```
$ whenever --update-crontab
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/whenever-0.10.0/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:77:in `popen': No such file or directory - crontab - (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/whenever-0.10.0/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:77:in `write_crontab'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/whenever-0.10.0/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:38:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/whenever-0.10.0/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:6:in `execute'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/whenever-0.10.0/bin/whenever:44:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/whenever:22:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/whenever:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever) is a Ruby gem that provides a clear syntax for writing and deploying **cron** jobs.

The software utility [**cron**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)  is a time-based job scheduler in **Unix-like** computer operating systems, you can't use it on windows machine.

[Setting up a cron job in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows#7195722)