# How to schedule email without opening that page using PHP

Tags: php

I want to schedule my email on particular time daily. Currently I am using windows task scheduler. But i want it to run without opening my page in browser. I am using windows.

Comment: What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use cron job... it will execute your script on scheduled time

Comment: can i use cron job in windows?

Comment: @Nilofar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

You can create the Cron Job for this purpose, To know more about the cron job please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php) post.

Comment: can i use cron job  in windows operating system

Comment: Yes you can create, refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows