# How to make a python file run as a seperate process/thread

Tags: python, multithreading, terminal, automation, process

I am **scraping** webs using beautifulsoap and Selenium in python.
in ubuntu when i run a python file like `python3 filename.py` then i didn't able to perform some other task in the same terminal, until that python script finish its execution.

Is there any way through which i run a python file from terminal and then make it independent from it. so that i can work on the same terminal while that python file is executing in background.

I will be thankful for your response.

Comment: Maybe that could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125493/how-to-constantly-run-python-script-in-the-background-on-windows

Comment: Which operating system are you using ?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run script in the background, in macOS and linux you can use:

```
python3 filename.py &
```

If you want your script will continue running after the terminal is closed, you can use:

```
nohup python3 filename.py &
```

Comment: Happy to help :) please consider accept the answer to help other developers who are running into same issue...

Comment: `nohup python3 -u file_name.py &`  could be much effective.