# How to keep my app running on background?

Tags: python, windows, exe

I have created an .exe file by pyinstaller. And I want it to run on background even if I close it and I want to be able to access it taskbar's arrow at the bottom-right corner. For example; when I close Discord, it disappears but I can access it from the taskbar's arrow at the bottom-right corner. I want to exact same thing to happen with my app, how can I do it?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389580/quick-and-easy-trayicon-with-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to constantly run Python script in the background on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125493/how-to-constantly-run-python-script-in-the-background-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

try this
pyinstaller -w --onefile "yourfile"
you should be good