# Error - filename.sh: python: command not found

Tags: python, error-handling

I am making a .Sh File which will in turn run a Python file cause I want that .Sh file to run in the background.

So here is the name of my Python File - `canlp.py`. And the .sh file code to run this Python file is as follows.

```
#!/bin/sh
CWD="$(pwd)"
python canlp.py
```

Although when I run this code it gives me this error in CMD - `canlp.sh: line 3: python: command not found` When I run it using `bash canlp.sh`

And I am able to run it from Standalone Terminal without using .Sh . I am using the latest version of Python and have Windows 10 as a Operating System

Comment: please add following details to question: 1. are you able to run it standalone from terminal? (without .sh) 2. which OS? Which python version are you using?

Depending on OS the steps would vary. eg for windows:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125493/how-to-constantly-run-python-script-in-the-background-on-windows#:~:text=On%20Windows%2C%20you%20can%20use,the%20program%20uses%20a%20GUI.

Comment: Did the changes now Sir

Comment: what i mean by standalone is:
If you just run "python canlp.py" from terminal (forget about .sh) does it run? If not, you have a larger problem worth solving 1st

Comment: I misunderstood u sir , The .py file runs smoothly in the terminal , The issue is with .sh file

Comment: You've tagged the question `bash` but you use `#!/bin/sh` as a she-bang. You'd better make that `#!/bin/bash` just to be sure that you actually run `bash`

Comment: Are you running this in `CMD`, `PowerShell` or `Ubuntu` (`bash` then I presume)?

Comment: I am using CMD sir

Comment: Seeif this helps: https://www.howtogeek.com/285082/how-to-run-windows-programs-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/

My guess is that bash is unable to access the binary coz pointers to it aree not added to the right directories

Comment: Read the article sir , Although tried using as mentioned in the article , Still the error remains the same

Comment: Actually i have not used windows at all for development so not sure about how to help.

One large suggestion i have is to use ubuntu if possible for development its muchmuch much more developer friendly. https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu-vs-windows/

Comment: @Jayshankarpure Can you run this [bash script](https://pastebin.com/QvFpKrC8) in CMD too? If there is a `python`, `python2` or `python3` installed (and in your PATH), it should find it.

Comment: Okay Sir , Will try using it

Comment: Thanks Sahil Sir , Any idea how can i install ubuntu parallely in my Windows laptop