# How to make django reload server without change any code after few hours?

Tags: django

I have develop a django apps, and i start the server by using python manage.py runserver. without stop the server and without edit any code I wish it reload the server after 24 hoursy, any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for this.

From Wikipedia:

```
# ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
# │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
# │ │ ┌───────────── day of the month (1 - 31)
# │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of the week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday;
# │ │ │ │ │                                   7 is also Sunday on some systems)
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# * * * * * command to execute
```

Comment: But my machine is window server

Comment: Here's a question that should be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Does it automatically reload when you edit one of its source files, like it does on Linux?

In that case, arrange for something to execute periodically, that "edits" a source file. Almost certainly, open for write and close is sufficient. On linux, `touch file.py` causes a restart. As a last resort  create a Python file that is imported by your project, containing a function that you don't actually use. To restart, replace it with a copy of itself.