# deleting data from the model django after a certain time

Tags: django

my model :

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    fio = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'fio', max_length = 100, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name ='phone', max_length = 16, null=True)
    date_register = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'date registers', max_length = 100, null=True) 
    date_visit = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'date visit', blank=True, null=True)
    time_visit = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'time visit', null=True,max_length = 100)
    verification = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

how to perform menegment-comand periodically, valid once an hour. Now I run the team `manage.py del`

```
import datetime
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.utils import timezone
from registers.models import Registration

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'delete unverified users'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):

        regs = Registration.objects.filter(verification__in=["False"])
        for a in regs:
            if a.date_register <= (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)):
                rg = Registration.objects.get(date_register = a.date_register.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
                rg.delete()
```

How to make this command work even when the site starts every hour (p.s. after running the `manage.py runserver` command)

Comment: You can look into cron job. Set a cron job on your server to run the script every hour. https://crontab.guru/every-1-hour

Comment: @Lian tried to do as in the tutorial  https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/ . when I enter the comand `python manage.py crontab add`  error  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'

Comment: You have to make sure that your cron executes the command from the correct python environment. Whatever you do to run the task manually (activate python env, run command), same has to be fed to the crontab (or other cron mgmt service).

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab/issues/34#issuecomment-219454337 . I can't use it on windows?

Comment: You can use anything that can schedule your runs, doesn't have to be crontab. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows.

Comment: I have not used django-crontab but on Linux servers, crontab is available. I'm assuming your server is Linux. Otherwise find out how to schedule tasks on your server. For crontab, the config is just a file containing the schedule time, and command to run. You can edit the config file with `crontab -e` and add your command there, with full path to the python executable and the manage.py file.

Comment: @Lian I wanted to test this mechanism on my pc. With embedded server in django

Comment: I would suggest if your server is Linux, test on the server. Not sure how you would do it on your computer (assuming Windows?) Maybe try WSL