# how to run a python script constantly for a day

Tags: python, windows

I have a python script that search for something in the internet.the script takes 2 minutes to finish.
after 2 minutes script will exit and the job is done.

but i want to run this script on my computer constantly for a day without stopping. it means i want to rerun the script after it's finished for a day.

i tried something like this so far:

```
status = True
def setstatus(stat):
    global status
    if staus:
       status = not stat
timer = Timer(1440,setstatus,[True])
timer.start()

while status:
   # do the job
```

any suggestion?

Comment: ``status = not status`` will only set the *local* variable ``status``. It will not set the *global* variable checked in ``while status``.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in another while loop which checks for the time now being 24hrs from when it started?

Comment: if you're on Linux you can create a cron job

Comment: If you are on Windows, then see [Setting up a cron job in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows#:~:text=The%20windows%20equivalent%20to%20a,add%20it%20to%20version%20control).)

Answer (score 0):

`time.time()` will give you the current time (in seconds from some time origin, in fact at the start of 1970). Calculate the end time by adding a number of seconds from the current time, and loop until then.

```
import time

end_time = time.time() + 86400

while time.time() < end_time:
    # do the job
```

Obviously this will keep using as much CPU as your job requires -- your stated aim is *"to run this script on my computer constantly for a day without stopping"* and this will do what you have asked for.  If in fact you want it to reduce CPU consumption by sleeping for a while on each iteration, then you can insert a `time.sleep(...)` in the loop (with sleep time value in seconds).

Answer (score -1):

Only works for GNU/Unix based systems.

You can use [Cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

For exemple, running a script everyday at 10 a.m.

Enter `crontab -e` in terminal.
Add `0 10 * * * /path/to/script.py` to the prompted file.

If you are using it with a web-scraper as your question states, you can have a shell script to encapsulate your python script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# setup variables
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
SCRIPT_FILE="path/to/python/script.py"
OUTPUT_FILE="path/to/save/outputs/${DATE}.json"

# activate virtualenv and run scrapy, for example
source path/to/venv/bin/activate
scrapy runspider ${SCRIPT_FILE} -o ${OUTPUT_FILE}
```

Comment: I'm familiar with cron . as you said it runs everyday at 10. but i want it to work for day

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. Running a script exactly for one day long and stop it then ? You need the same script to restart consistently during one day or the python script will be dedicated to that ? Can you precise what you are looking for please ?