# Can we schedule Selenium(Python) program to run after every 5 minutes in Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scheduled-tasks

I am currently working on a project in which the values have to be parsed automatically every 5 minutes.

I'm done with the project to parse values once. Using Python-Selenium.

Can someone help?

Comment: while loop with `time.sleep(300)`?

Comment: I am doing that currently, I feel it is not the optimum method. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the windows equivalent to a cron job, it is a scheduled task.

You will run your selenium program on a schedule.

See the Microsoft documentation on [Schtasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/orphan-topics/ws.10/cc772785(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

You can read more about [scheduling-a-python-script](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/analytics/scheduling-a-python-script-or-model-to-run-at-a-prescribed-time/?rmedium=redirect&rsource=blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip)

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7195722/6845383) of [@steenhulthin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587279/steenhulthin) for more explanation.