# How can I make Python run at a specific time everyday and make it repeat every hour?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I made a Python script to remind me to drink water every hour. My code is:

```
import time
import plyer
from plyer import notification

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        plyer.notification.notify(
            title="Go and Drink Water!",
            message="You need to drink at least 3.5 litres of water Everyday. Being Dehydrated can decrease Brain Function and Energy levels.",
            app_icon="C:\\Users\\(My username)\\(location of icon)",
            timeout=10,
        )
        time.sleep(60 * 60)
```

I put the python path and this script's path in a .bat file and made it run everyday at 8:35am using Task Scheduler. It did run at 8:35am but it didn't repeat. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong or suggest a better method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows

Comment: @techytushar I didn't really understand anything from that post you linked...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up a cron job in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

use python APScheduler module: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html#code-examples