# Jupyter notebook schedule automatically

Tags: python, jupyter

Does anybody knows how to schedule a jupyter notebook every hour or 30 minutes?

I tried to use seekwell (https://app.seekwell.io/) but it did not work for me.

Does anybody have another solution

thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by schedule? please elaborate

Comment: I mean to have the notebook running every hour automatically and updating a google sheet. The code already update the google sheet I just need to set this schedule to run every hour

Answer (score 2):

Save your jupyter notebook as .py file

I would like to give credit to @Vincent Stevenson

Go to `Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Task Scheduler--> Create Task`

1. Task Scheduler, Create Task
2. Give the Task a title
3. Go to Actions
4. Go to CMD to find the path,

   Python, import sys, sys.executable

   (this tells you what the **Program/script field** should be populated with: "some path
   with Appdata mostly")

   like:C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
5. **Arguments**: name of the python script (like run.py)
6. **Start in**: dir location of python script (like:C:\Users\admin\Documents\my_python_project)
7. Go to Triggers, schedule for every 30 minutes
8. Test the script by running it

Answer (score 1):

According to the article [5 ways to schedule Jupyter Notebook](https://mljar.com/blog/schedule-jupyter-notebook/) there are several approaches to scheduling a notebook.

### 1. Cron

You can use cron scheduler if you are on UNIX machine. You define the frequency of the execution in the crontab. To execute notebook as script you can use [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

### 2. Windows Task Scheduler

Windows user can use Windows Task Scheduler with nbconvert or papermill.

### 3. Mercury

You can use the [`Mercury`](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) framework for scheduling. You need to add the YAML header in the notebook, below is the example:

```yaml
title: My notebook
description: My notebook executed automatically
schedule: '0 * * * *'
notify:
    on_success: email1@example.com
    attachment: pdf
```

What is more, you can set a list of emails that will receive the notebook in PDF format by email after successful execution. Here is a [notebook scheduling documentation](https://mercury-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schedule/).

Below is an example of a notebook scheduled in the `Mercury`. You can see that there is a green box in the sidebar with information about scheduling. The notebook can also be easily accessed as a web app and downloaded as a PDF.

[image: Scheduled notebook web app]

You can read more about [scheduling notebooks to make automated PDF reports](https://mljar.com/blog/automated-reports-python/) and making [dashboards in Python with automatic updates](https://mljar.com/blog/python-dashboard/) on the MLJAR blog.

### 4. Notebooker

The next open source framework for notebooks scheduling is [Notebooker](https://github.com/man-group/notebooker). It is a Flask based application for scheduling and sharing notebooks.

[image]

[image]

### 5. Web-based notebooks

There are several notebook in the cloud services that offer scheduling:

- [DeepNote](https://deepnote.com)
- [DataBricks](https://databricks.com)
- [NaaS](https://naas.ai)
- [Noteable](https://noteable.io)

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago, an open-source JupyterLab extension called [*Jupyter Scheduler*](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter-scheduler/) was released and it does exactly what you need. Very easy to use from within JupyterLab and *no need to save the notebook as a Python file* ️

You can find a very good introduction here: https://blog.jupyter.org/introducing-jupyter-scheduler-f9e82676c388

Note that the minimum JupyterLab version currently seems to be 3.5. (It did not work for me with 3.4.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are Linux user, then simply create a python script and add it to your crontab to run every few hours.

If you are windows, then also you need to create python script and instead of crontab use scheduled tasks:

[Setting up a cron job in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows)

Comment: i`m actually using OS

Comment: MAC OS has the crontab feature. Just copy and paste your jupyter code to python script and do crontab -e then add this: 30 * * * * /path/to/python_script.sh >> /path/to/llogs_script.txt 30--> is minutes, set it to 60 for 1 hour

Comment: I never used this feature before. Do you know a tutorial I can follow?

Comment: https://medium.com/better-programming/https-medium-com-ratik96-scheduling-jobs-with-crontab-on-macos-add5a8b26c30

Comment: kindly tick my answer, if you found it working for you. @MarianaRodrigues

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can use [Deepnote] (http://deepnote.com/). You can run your Jupyter notebooks using the free cloud platform Deepnote. You can simply set Deepnote to run at a given interval and close the window. This will ensure that no added actions are needed for you to execute the notebook at the given time.

Furthermore, you can select to be notified by email if your notebook stops working in Deepnote.