# Send scheduled email django

Tags: python, django, email, celery

I have made a small django app to fit all my needs. I will use it on my company level to track simple tasks of couple mehanical engineers. Now, only thing left is to send scheduled emails in my Django app (every day at noon, if someone is behind with work, he would get an email). Since I'm using Windows and I'll deploy this app on Windows, I can't use cron job (this only works on Linux, as I've seen on forums), which is simple and easy. Only way I found so far was using django-celery-beat. This is not so easy to set up, and I need to run 'worker' each time I run my server. This is a bit above my level and I would need to learn a lot more (and it needs to have a message broker, like RabbitMQ, which I also need to run and learn to implement).

I was wondering is there a more easy way to send a simple email every day at noon? I don't want to install additional apps, I wish to keep it simple as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up a cron job in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows)

Comment: Unfortunately no, because I need to use it inside my Django app

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that only with Django. Check this https://medium.com/@django.course/7-ways-to-execute-scheduled-jobs-with-python-47d481d22b91

Comment: There is a https://github.com/rq/django-rq which seems simpler than celery (although I've never used it), but it still requires Redis to run. You can install and run Redis via Docker if you are already using it, or install Redis on Windows directly

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Dockerizing Django with Redis and Celery.
Dockerizing is the process of packing, deploying, and running applications using Docker containers.
please use the below link to read more about dockerizing

[Dockerizing](https://developerexperience.io/practices/dockerizing)

[Dockerizing Django with Postgres, Redis and Celery](https://soshace.com/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-redis-and-celery/)