# How to schedule a AWS CLI script on Windows EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a `Windows EC2 instance` in place. I cannot delete it every day since we have multiple tools installed like accessing `Postgress RDS` via `Dbeaver`. Now, we have an activity of deleting a few `S3 folders`. So using the `Mobaxterm` tool, I can delete it via `AWS CLI` commands.

However, I am unable to schedule this script which runs once daily in the morning. I explored a few posts which are not relevant to my problem. There, the user is trying to `launch > run script > delete instance` which I don't want to do.

What can be done in my case?

Comment: [schedule a task in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least two options come to mind:

1. Use Windows task scheduler to create a task that will run your script daily directly on the instance
2. Use AWS Systems Manager State Manager to run a custom document that will execute your script remotely on a daily basis

I would recommend the second option because you would be able to reuse it for other instances if needed.